# Using APscheduler with Textual in Python

Tags: python, rich

i need a scheduler in a Textual application to periodically query an external data source. As a test i've tried to use APscheduler to call a `tick()` function every second.

However nothing happens although the scheduler should be started.

What is going on and how to debug this?

```py
from textual.app import App, ComposeResult
from textual.containers import Horizontal, Vertical
from textual.widgets import *

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
 

class HeaderApp(App):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sched = BackgroundScheduler()
        self.sched.add_job(self.tick,'interval', seconds=1)
        self.sched.start()
        super(HeaderApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def compose(self) -> ComposeResult:
        yield Header()
        yield TextLog()
        
    def tick(self):
        text_log = self.query_one(TextLog)
        text_log.write("tick")
        
    def on_mount(self):
        text_log = self.query_one(TextLog)
        text_log.write(self.sched.running)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = HeaderApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `apscheduler`, but since you haven't had a response, could you use the builtin `set_interval` which will call a method at regular intervals?

```py
from textual.app import App, ComposeResult
from textual.containers import Horizontal, Vertical
from textual.widgets import *


class HeaderApp(App):
    def compose(self) -> ComposeResult:
        yield Header()
        yield TextLog()

    def tick(self):
        text_log = self.query_one(TextLog)
        text_log.write("tick")

    def on_mount(self):
        self.set_interval(1, self.tick)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = HeaderApp()
    app.run()
```